# nginx+gunicorn+django SSL not working, on Chrome it gives ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, which is "This site can't provide a secure connection."

Tags: nginx, ssl, django, web-hosting, gunicorn

I've just finished setting up an nginx+gunicorn+django web server (after having virtually the same problem with apache2+wsgi+django), and confirmed it works perfectly over http. After running letsencrypt's certbot, it redirects http to https correctly, however, my browser then lands on the error mentioned in the title. I've spent many hours now trying everything I could think of, and have now come to here. Some of the commented-out lines in the files may reveal some of the things I've tried so far.

P.S. I tried running ssllabs and check-your-website and neither returned anything useful/that I didn't already know.

### Additional Info (some of this may not be needed but some might be helpful)

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
nginx nginx/1.14.0
Django 2.2.5
Python 3.6
gunicorn 19.9.0

Domain is from Google Domains using the googledomains protocol in ddclient for DDNS

### Files

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite

upstream your-gunicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name mysite.net;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.error_log;
    root /home/user/Desktop/Django/mysite;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/user/Desktop/Django/mysite/static/;
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://your-gunicorn;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nerd-squad.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nerd-squad.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = mysite.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80 default;
  server_name mysite.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

```
# <Django mysite root>/gunicorn/gunicorn-config.py

import multiprocessing

bind = 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock'
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
reload = True
daemon = True
accesslog = './access.log'
errorlog = './error.log'
```

```
# <Django Site Root>/mysite/settings.py

"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = <nope>

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    <nope>
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'pics.apps.PicsConfig',
    'welcome.apps.WelcomeConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),
]

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/Desktop/Django/static'


#SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

```
# nginx -t

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

```
# /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf

# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_ciphers <nope>;
```

I can provide additional info if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Have you restarted nginx? What does `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf` contain? What does `nginx - t` say?

Comment: @Ginnungagap I've restarted nginx multiple times (after every configuration change), and I've now posted what you asked to the original post.

Comment: Are SSL ciphers really `<nope>` or did you redact that?

Comment: Yes, I'm not about to reveal the SSL keys/ciphers online. Those are not `<nope>` in the original file.

Comment: Okay, ciphers are basically public information but do what you will, I assume NGINX would have complained about them if they were bad. Can you serve static content over HTTPS (ie. just remove every location and serve a near empty folder)?